# Make reverse TCP connection accept any amount of connections (like a normal TCP server)

Tags: go, networking, tcp, proxy, http-proxy

I'm trying to create a reverse proxy to a [CONNECT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/CONNECT)-based HTTP proxy. The user who wants to use the proxy just treats `machine A` as an HTTP proxy. It works the following way:

1. `machine B` opens a TCP socket to `machine A`.
2. On `machine A`, a TCP socket is exposed on a port and all the incoming data is tunneled to `machine B` (io.Copy).
3. On `machine B`, all the data is tunneled to the local HTTP server and the socket to `machine A`.

Essentially this is a reverse-proxy behind an HTTP proxy. The reason it's this complex is because the HTTP proxy is behind NAT (on `machine B`) and therefore not accessible directly. The use case is being able to host an HTTP proxy behind a NAT.

Machine A tunnel (Go):

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net"
)

func Conn(c *net.TCPConn) string {
    return c.RemoteAddr().String() + " (" + c.LocalAddr().String() + ")"
}

func ProxifyConns(recipientConn, donorConn *net.TCPConn) {
    log.Println("Proxying", ConnrecipientConn), "and", Conn(donorConn))
    go func() {
        _, err := io.Copy(recipientConn, donorConn)
        if err != nil {
            utils.StacktraceError(err)
        }
        recipientConn.Close()
    }()
    go func() {
        _, err := io.Copy(donorConn, recipientConn)
        if err != nil {
            utils.StacktraceError(err)
        }
        recipientConn.Close()
    }()
}


func main() {
    // Open the donor listener
    donorsAddr, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp4", ":11000")
    if err != nil {
        utils.StacktraceErrorAndExit(err)
    }
    listenerDonors, err := net.ListenTCP("tcp", donorsAddr)
    if err != nil {
        utils.StacktraceErrorAndExit(err)
    }
    defer listenerDonors.Close()
    log.Println("Listening for donors on", listenerDonors.Addr())

    // Open the recipient listener
    recipientsAddr, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp4", ":10000")
    if err != nil {
        utils.StacktraceErrorAndExit(err)
    }
    listenerRecipients, err := net.ListenTCP("tcp", recipientsAddr)
    if err != nil {
        utils.StacktraceErrorAndExit(err)
    }
    defer listenerRecipients.Close()
    log.Println("Listening for recipients on", listenerRecipients.Addr())

    //  Handle donor connections
    donorConns := make(chan *net.TCPConn)
    go func() {
        for {
            donorConn, err := listenerDonors.AcceptTCP()
            donorConn.SetKeepAlive(true)
            if err != nil {
                utils.StacktraceErrorAndExit(err)
                return
            }
            log.Println("New donor connection from", Conn(donorConn))
            donorConns <- donorConn
        }
    }()

    // Handle recipient connections
    for {
        recipientConn, err := listenerRecipients.AcceptTCP()
        recipientConn.SetKeepAlive(true)
        if err != nil {
            utils.StacktraceErrorAndExit(err)
            return
        }
        log.Println("New recipient connection from", Conn(recipientConn))
        donorConn := <-donorConns
        proxy.ProxifyConns(recipientConn, donorConn)
    }
}
```

Machine B tunnel (Node.js):

```
import net, { AddressInfo } from 'net';
import http from 'http';
import golgi from 'golgi';

export const startHttpProxy = () => {
  const server = http.createServer();
  let proxyServer: http.Server = golgi(server);
  // Listening to 0 assigns a random OS-assigned port
  proxyServer = proxyServer.listen(0);
  return proxyServer;
};

export const startDonorSocket = () => {
  const proxyServer = startHttpProxy();
  const proxyServerSocket = new net.Socket();
  proxyServerSocket.connect(
    (proxyServer.address() as AddressInfo).port,
    '127.0.0.1'
  );

  const donorSocket = new net.Socket();
  donorSocket.setKeepAlive(true);
  donorSocket.connect(11000, '2.226.102.14', () => {
    proxyServerSocket.pipe(donorSocket);
    donorSocket.pipe(proxyServerSocket);
  });
};
```

Unfortunately this works when tunneling to one TCP address but not when tunneling to more. If I open many Machine B tunnels (Node.js code), it works. What I mean is that a donor connection (Node.js) is "consumed" ever time it is taken by a recipient (HTTP proxy user) because a persistent TCP tunnel is made on it.

I wonder is there is a way to make this work for any amount of TCP connections, not just one. My only idea right now is to create more TCP donor connections every time a connection is consumed but I wonder if there is a simpler solution.

Comment: You have not provided enough info to determine how the code above is used, but judging by the lack of synchronization around the goroutines I suspect your proxy handler is returning while the connection is still running.

Comment: By the way, I used to solve the same problem by running `ssh hostOutsideNat -R 4000:localhost:4000`. This would open port 4000 on the `hostOutsideNat` and forward every TCP to the host inside NAT. This works for local work/browsing; but, as it's encrypted, it puts some pressure on CPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
go func() {
    for {
        donorConn, err := listenerDonors.AcceptTCP()
        donorConn.SetKeepAlive(true)
        if err != nil {
            utils.StacktraceErrorAndExit(err)
            return
        }
        log.Println("New donor connection from", Conn(donorConn))
        donorConns <- donorConn
    }
}()
```

You start processing the first TCP connection. This code blocks on `donorConns <- donorConn`. Until this send to channel finishes the loop won't go into the second iteration (and the next TCP connection won't be accepted).

You do a very similar second loop

```
// Handle recipient connections
for {
    recipientConn, err := listenerRecipients.AcceptTCP()
    recipientConn.SetKeepAlive(true)
    if err != nil {
        utils.StacktraceErrorAndExit(err)
        return
    }
    log.Println("New recipient connection from", Conn(recipientConn))
    donorConn := <-donorConns
    proxy.ProxifyConns(recipientConn, donorConn)
}
```

which requires `donorConn := <-donorConns` to complete (from the first loop) and requires `proxy.ProxifyConns(recipientConn, donorConn)` to complete.

I'm not sure how you intend the whole thing to work, but, most likely, you need a very minor change:
`go proxy.ProxifyConns(recipientConn, donorConn)`

Comment: Proxying connections on a goroutine makes everything faster but my the main problem remains the same. That is, how to make sure there would be enough TCP connections everytime. Do I create a new one every time a donor connection is consumed? Would this be enough?

Comment: There are indeed some limits: a) avaiable ports (since remote and local IPs are fixed, there only resource is port), b) file descriptors (see `ulimit -Sa` for soft limit, `ulimit -Ha`

Comment: Sorry about not giving the bounty to you as I though there is no limit on time when you can give it.